# How to read excel file in Java when the file is located within the java project?

Tags: java, selenium

What should be the syntax when the excel file that I'm trying to call is imported within the project.

[image: please see this image for my setup ad code]

Comment: I guess this is not a duplicate cos that topic shows path on the local file. i need syntax on how to locate the file based on the project specified on the photo attached

Comment: Pls don't put just screenshot of your issue/error it's batter to add description of your image too ,as well If those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
 public class ReadFileExcel
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
        {
            ClassLoader classLoader = new ReadFileExcel.getClass().getClassLoader();
            File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("./dashboards.xlsx").getFile());
            // replace the below one with the above but just change the name of the class
            var file = new FileInputStream("Dashboard.xlsx");
        }
    }
```

Note : Build the project, otherwise classloader will not able to read.

Comment: i'm not sure where part should i change these line of yours on my side. ClassLoader classLoader = new ReadFileExcel.getClass().getClassLoader();

Comment: ClassLoader classLoader = new {class where you are reading thefile}.getClass().getClassLoader();

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you are using is correct but make sure your using the correct path of your local file.

When your local file is in the same package/folder where you write your codes.Just write down its file name.

> var file = new FileInputStream("Dashboard.xlsx");

or try using Absolute path of your filename.

> var file = new FileInputStream("M3A FrontEndPoc/Dashboard.xlsx");

Comment: still cant find the specific path